# Using scale_fill_manual to change the colour of a specific bar in an R ggplot barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, highlight

I'm making a barchart of the following data frame, df, and trying to make the 'Britain' bar light blue and the other bars steel blue:

```
t   first_column second_column ToHighlight
1       Britain          32.5         yes
2     Australia          69.8          no
3 United States         293.1          no
4        Canada          70.1          no
Type here
```

The 'ToHighlight' column is there so that I can set a condition for scale_fill_manual to colour the 'Britain' bar light blue and all the others steel blue.

I have no problem rendering the chart with ALL bars in steel blue using the following:

```
economist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(first_column, +second_column),y = second_column)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "steel blue") + coord_flip() + ggtitle("Size matters", subtitle = "Average total holdings of the ten largest pension funds in billions of US dollars, selected countries") + theme_economist() + theme(text = element_text(family = "Verdana")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

But using the code below to try and make the Britain bar light blue with all others steel blue renders me a chart with all the bars in the default grey colour.

```
economist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(first_column, +second_column),y = second_column)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("yes"="lightblue", "no"="steel blue", guide = FALSE)) + coord_flip() + ggtitle("Size matters", subtitle = "Average total holdings of the ten largest pension funds in billions of US dollars, selected countries") + theme_economist() + theme(text = element_text(family = "Verdana")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

What do I need to do to fix my code? I'd be really grateful for help, have been playing around for a while now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  first_column = c("Britain", "Australia", "United States", "Canada"),
  second_column = c(32.5, 69.8, 293.1, 70.1),
  ToHighlight = c("yes", "no", "no", "no")
)

economist <- ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(first_column, +second_column), y=second_column, fill=ifelse(ToHighlight=="yes", "Britain", "Others"))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=c("Britain"="lightblue", "Others"="steelblue"), guide="none") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  ggtitle("Size matters", subtitle = "Average total holdings of the ten largest pension funds in billions of US dollars, selected countries") + 
  theme_economist() + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Verdana")) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

Note the ifelse-function within fill.